# Upsert in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-warehouse, amazon-redshift, upsert

I have one DW table into which I'm inserting data from a staging table. The DW table contains 5 column and I'm essentially checking if a combination of all the 5 columns already exists in the DW table while picking from the staging table, if it exists then I don't make an insert (or update) and skip that row (as it already exists).

On the other hand if there is any row that exists without the combination of the 5 columns then I make an insert.

Is there a way achieve this using upsert. As I'm not doing any update operation here (insert only and delete(which is ignore insert)). I'm not sure if upsert would be the right choice.

Answer (score 8):

There is no such thing as `UPSERT` in Redshift, see their [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-upsert.html). If you intend to load only rows into a table which are not already included, then this should do the trick:

```
insert into target_table
    select
        *
    from
        source_table
    left join
        target_table using(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
    where
        target_table.col1 is null
;
```

Comment: May I ask what to do with multiple unique keys?

Comment: @xbeta can you explain a bit more what you mean, i.e. which rows you'd like to insert and which you'd want to ignore? My example above would assume that the combination of `col1`-`col5` is the unique key. However, you can amend the `using` and `where` clauses to fit your case.

Comment: should this not be 


insert into target_table
    select
        source_table.*
    from
        source_table
    left join
        target_table using(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
    where
        target_table.col1 is null;

Comment: @pranjal I don't see a difference between your comment and the code in my reply.

Comment: just edited my code

Comment: @pranjal This is a very abstract example in any case. As the specific question here is about a staging table, we can assume the schema of `source_table` and `target_table` to be identical. Real world scenarios might look different.