# Inserting data into one table from second table on multiple join condition

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl

I am trying to insert data in one table (`trgt_tbl`) from a second table (`src_tbl`) using join on key fields. The query seems to work fine but it's extremely slow. There are around 16 mil records in `trgt_tbl` and every daily delta load from `src_tbl` is expected to have around 500k records. I am trying to figure out if I can do it in a better way.

Note: Merge is not an option since data is inserted in Redshift and Redshift doesn't support merge.

```
INSERT INTO trgt_tbl (col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    col5,
    col6)
SELECT col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    col5,
    col6 
FROM  src_tbl s  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM trgt_tbl t 
    WHERE 
        t.col1 = s.col1 
        OR t.col2 = s.col2 
        OR t.col3 = s.col3
        OR t.col4 = s.col4 
)
```

Comment: What is your actual goal? Are you wanting to do the equivalent of an `UPSERT`? Have you reviewed the examples in [Updating and Inserting New Data - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html#merge-method-replace-existing-rows)?

Comment: yes, it is an upsert.

Comment: but i am trying to handle an upsert using multiple keys here which is the challenge.

Comment: How about: [Upsert in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38789642/174777)

Comment: i tried that way but getting the error message:  Invalid operation: relation "trgt_tbl" does not exist;

Comment: Could you add the command that you tried to your Question, together with the exact error message?

Comment: i was able to resolve the issue related to relation but i am missing records from source when running the below query.

Comment: `INSERT INTO trgt_tbl (col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    col5,
    col6)
SELECT col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    col5,
    col6 from src_tbl s left outer join trgt_tbl t using(col1, col2, col3)            
    where t.col1 is null or t.col2 is null or t.col3 is null and s.col6 not in ('x')`

Comment: Then you should debug it by finding records that you think should have been added, but weren't, and then determine why the query did not find them.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionend in the [Database Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html) due to the missing support of `merge` / `upsert` you should use a combination of updates and inserts with the help of a staging table to perform the merging efficiently. E.g. you can do the following:

Create a staging table with the data from `src_tbl`:

```
create temp table staging (like target); 
insert into staging select s.col1, s.col2, s.col3, s.col4, s.col5, s.col6 from src_tbl s JOIN trgt_tbl t ON 
    t.col1 = s.col1 
    OR t.col2 = s.col2 
    OR t.col3 = s.col3
    OR t.col4 = s.col4;
```

Inner join the staging table to remove the rows from `trgt_tbl` that are being updated and insert the rows from the staging table:

```
begin transaction;

delete from trgt_tbl using staging where t.col1 = s.col1 OR t.col2 = stage.col2 OR t.col3 = stage.col3 OR t.col4 = stage.col4; 
insert into trgt_tbl select * from staging;

end transaction;
```

Comment: well thanks for the answer. but my source table is already in Redshift and is updated daily with delta records only for the last day which needs to be updated, inserted or deleted in the target table. Hence, i don't think that it is necessary to create another staging table for doing the same join. Let me know if i am missing something.